# Highlight all instances of a search in Preview

Tags: preview, search

When I use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search for a word or phrase in Preview, it finds all instances of the search in the document, but only highlights the matched areas when I click on a specific page on the lefthand sidebar (that lists each page with a match and the number of matches per page).

Current behavior: I search for a word, and it finds a match on pages 1, 2, and 3. It brings me to page 1 and shows all instances of the word highlighted. If I scroll down to page 2, none of the page 2 instances are highlighted. However, if I click on page 2 on the left sidebar, it will then highlight all instances on that page.

Expected behavior: When I scroll to page 2, all instances will be highlighted without me having to click on page 2 on the left sidebar.

Is there any way to do this?

(I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.5)

Comment: There does not appear to be. I tested this on OS X 10.11 and it still works the same way.

Comment: It got worse. My Preview does not highlight multiple results at all, even though I click the page thumbnail. When I iterate through the results it temporarily highlights for a second then makes it a selection (light blue background). But no concurrent highlights of multiple findings (even on the same page).

Comment: @tozCSS I am facing the exact same problem as you mentioned. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @AnshKhurana it looks like mine got fixed at some point but I'm not sure how, Catalina upgrade maybe?

Comment: @tozCSS I am on macOS Catalina and I am still facing this issue.

Comment: I highly recommend switching to PDF Expert for reading and annotating PDFs. It can highlight searches across pages and hasn't had any of the bugs I've found in Preview. (I'm not affiliated at all, just a happy consumer who was getting tired of trying to find work arounds for all the Preview inefficiencies).